# How can I dual-boot Windows and Fedora with two hard disks?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, multi-boot, fedora-15

I have an 80GB and a 40GB hard drive. My primary hard drive contains Windows. On the second hard drive, I want to install Fedora 15.

When the system boots, there should be a menu to select the operating system. Is this possible? Where do I install the boot loader? On the primary or the secondary hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have XP on primary then simply install Fedora on the second drive. Most Linux editions can detect Windows (or other system) and will work just fine without worries.

Comment: I have two hard disk 80+40 GB.windows install on 80GB and i want to install fedora from second hard disk.other question where to install boot loader(primary/secondary HD).

Comment: I don't think it's important where you'll install it. Let Fedora worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

Open BIOS setup, open boot priority, put the 40GB Hard disk as 1st boot, save and restart. Put the DVD containing Fedora and install on 40GB. Install GRUB2 Linux Bootloader in the 1st Hard drive where Windows XP has been installed. Now the Linux Bootloader will install on top of the Windows Bootloader and Fedora will show as first boot and Windows 2nd boot options.